# Still getting Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES even after chmod 755 android/gradlew

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to run this Android app for a while in my Macbook through an emulator, but I'm still getting these errors despite trying everything.

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried chmod gradlew and ./gradlew clean and it still would not start. I even checked back with the SDK manager and downloaded some stuff I forgot, but it still persisted with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

try run this in your terminal

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

The chmod command sets the permissions of files or directories. The above error seems to relate to probably some access issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the root of your project and then run the chmod command.

```
cd root/of/your/project
sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew
```